# What are the tools needed to best asses a load balancer?

Tags: cpu-usage, docker, network-traffic, traffic-management

I'm building a Paas with Docker container in the field of Networkf Function Virtualization. I need to deploy some load-balancers inside containers.

I need to asses the load balancers in differents scenarios and under different metrics like CPU usage, Mermory usage, etc.

I'm mainly looking for traffic generator tools like pktgen.

Any one can point me out some tools that I might use ?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[Nping](http://nmap.org/nping/) and possibly [Nmap](http://nmap.org/) seem like they might be good tools.  You could also take a look at the tools included with [Wireshark](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools).  I have used those tools to generate lots of traffic and packets on a network, but normally to debug network issues and we never had a load balancer of any sort.